# Making grok views to look template from a parent directory in Plone

Tags: plone, zope, grok

If I try

```
  grok.templatedir("../browser/templates")
```

I get

```
  GrokImportError: The 'templatedir' directive can not contain path separator.
```

What's the correct way to set five.grok template directory to an absolute path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"grok.templatedir(directory) - directory - the name of the directory inside **the same package** as the module"*

I fear that at the moment there isn't a correct way, indeed there is no way.

There is a [pending bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/grok/1.3/+bug/250977) about this and eventually there will be a refactoring.

More info:

- http://grok.zope.org/doc/current/reference/directives.html#grok.templatedir
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/grok/1.3/+bug/250977
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/grok/+bug/562262

Answer (score -1):

```
In [1]: from os.path import dirname, join
In [2]: import zopeskel.basic_zope
In [3]: join(dirname(zopeskel.basic_zope.__file__))
Out[3]: '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ZopeSkel-2.19-py2.6.egg/zopeskel'
```

but - I dunno if this is the correct way.

best,
marco

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't make any sense, or at least not with this question.